# Fastest data storage method for looking up text in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm storing some details about notable people such as their names and dates of birth, along with a list of their quotes, structured into one long string

I'd like to be able to quickly search for a specific word or phrase, and return the name(s) of the people who have this word or phrase in their quotes. At the moment I am using a Pandas dataframe and it looks like this:

```
            name.value             dob.value                                             quotes
0       Jacinda Ardern  1980-07-26T00:00:00Z  ...for other women, it is totally unacceptable...
1          Helen Clark  1950-02-26T00:00:00Z  Girls can do anything. We do do anything and w...
2  Sonny Bill Williams  1985-08-03T00:00:00Z  I feel that if I am busting my arse, if I am s...
3        Peter Jackson  1961-10-31T00:00:00Z  Fantasy is an 'F' word that hopefully the five...
4  Katherine Mansfield  1888-10-14T00:00:00Z  Would you not like to try all sorts of lives —...
```

but I'm not sure this is the way to store this information for fastest access, or how to search efficiently for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will return a list of the people who has the particular word in their quotes. And for searching efficiently I believe `contains` does a fairly good job.

```
def search_name(word):
    return df['name.value'].loc[df['quotes'].str.contains(word)].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is similar to @Shivam's answer, but requires one fewer index command:

```py
df.loc[df['quotes'].str.contains(word),'name.value']
```

Comment: Thank you for the credit, I realised I had a few issues in my code. I changed it. But your method works perfectly.